# Undefined type in Cloud Functions Realtime Database trigger

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to develop a Cloud Function that takes the value of an amount, then takes the total and add's the amount onto that total before re-writing the total with the new amount.

so far this is what i have:

```
    exports.newRequest = functions.database.ref("/aRef/{aUID}/{bUID}").onCreate((snapshot, context) =>{
    var requestSnapshot = snapshot.data;
    console.log('Testing stuff',  context.params.aUID);
    var UID= context.params.aUID;
    var thisAmount= requestSnapshot.child('amount').val();
    var totalAmount= functions.database.child('aRef').child('bRef').child(UID).child('totalAmount').val();
    var finalAmount = totalAmount+ thisAmount;
    return functions.database().ref(`aRef/bRef/${UID}/totalAmount`).set(finalAmount);

});
```

and this is the error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Id' of undefined
    at exports.newRequest.functions.database.ref.onWrite.context (/user_code/index.js:14:44)
    at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:114:23)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:144:20)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:827:24
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

I understand that the error leads me to line 14 which in this case is trying to get the value of `{Id}` but don't understand how to rectify it?

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition is way off.  It should accept a first parameter, which is a snapshot, and a second parameter, which is a context.  What you have right now looks like it's trying to combine both objects into a single parameter called `context`.

You might want to go back to [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) and learn about how database onWrite triggers work.

Comment: thanks for the steer but it doesn't lead to to the answer

Comment: so i've decided that a onCreate call is better for my use case and included (snapshot, context) however, the context.params.aUID is still throwing the same error?  Thanks for helping with this, not new to coding but for some reason JavaScript seems to spin me out.

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit of digging and a lead from Doug Stevenson, i was incorrectly calling / trying to get data from the context rather than the snapshot and trying to get data from another area of my DB without putting in a .once().then() to retrieve the snapshot. I also didn't need an onWrite method, but a onCreate method.

Final code below for anyone who needs it.

```
exports.onRequest = functions.database.ref("/Donations/{UID}").onCreate((snapshot, context) =>{
        var requestSnapshot = snapshot.val();
        var ID = snapshot.child('toid').val();    
        var thisAmount = snapshot.child('amount').val();
        var database = admin.database().ref(`/users/charity/${ID}/acc/totalAmount`);
        return database.once('value').then (snapshot =>{
        var totalAmount = snapshot.val();
        var finalAmount = totalAmount + thisAmount; 
         console.log('status',  snapshot.child('amount').val());
        return database.set(finalAmount); 

        });
        });
```